# Advice for moving from WP8/WPF to android development

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, xamarin

I'm a WPF and WP8 developer and I'm planning to develop all my current apps for android too. I did some research and read a little about android development. From what I've read, Android's XML is terrible compared to XAML. The tags are long and terrible (For example, why couldn't they just have Width instead of android:layout_width ?) And the most annoying part was that there is no equivalent for data binding.
So, I looked into alternatives and came across Xamarin, which seems a better. But I have a few questions I was hoping someone would help me with.

1. My biggest question is should I go for Xamarin or go ahead making native android apps in java? Is there any disadvantage on using Xamarin? Because there is a good thing about it that I can reuse most of my code..
2. Is there data binding like functionality in it?
3. Does Xamarin support all features that a native app would? Will I be able to get Material UI design templates in it?

Also, if you have any other advice or suggestions do let me know.. Thanks

Comment: You may want to load and use the Android Studio (1.0 released recently). Your complaints about how Android is defined won't really get you anywhere. Just use an IDE that helps your development as you adhere to the current definitions and requirements for "app" development.

Comment: Yes. I have that downloaded. I'm not complaining really. I'm just not used to working without certain things. And honestly, I have no idea how to display data in a listview yet. Which is why I'm struggling..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be.

1)
Take it easy. Android development is not that bad. 
It is true, you do not have data binding facilities as you have in WP but that is not end of the world. 
Android xml is simple and it beautifully solves the issue of different screen sizes and types. 
You have to write more code in android than in WP. WP came after android which allowed Microsoft to come up with better development patterns for rapid development.

2)
Big no for Xamarin. Xamarin reduces your options because it relays on android library wrappers in c#. Only benefit of Xamarin is to have common business logic. that is normally 5% percent of  any project. In most cases you would find yourself in very tight situation; for instance, if there is any good 3rd party android library that you want to use in your project then you have to wait Xamarin wrapper for this library in order to use it.

3) Not always, you would find restrictions

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I guess you are right. I'll have to stick with making 2 apps. I'm too used to MVVM and data binding in WPF which might be causing all this problem for me

Comment: You can share code among multiple apps.  Just structure you code properly. For example, you may want to create some common code branch with general code; make specific code for each app and combine the two.